# Add color code support to a Bukkit plugin

Tags: java, bukkit

I would like to add color code support to my `config.yml`. How do I correctly add `translateAlternateColorCode` to my code?

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player  player = (Player) sender;
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("member")) {
            player.sendMessage(getConfig().getString("MemberText"));
        }
```

Comment: Did you try using the section sign (§)?

Comment: no i want to use the & sign in the config to enable colors.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use `translateAltranateColorCodes`. Here's an example:

```
String nonColoredText = getConfig().getString("MemberText"); //get the raw string from "MemberText"
String coloredText = translateAlternateColorCodes('&', nonColoredText); //translate alt color codes
```

The above would change any text that began with an `&` sign to it's correct color code. For example, if `&a` was in the config, it would change it to the green color, or `ChatColor.GREEN`, making the message show up green. This works with other characters, too. Like if you wanted to use a `$` sign for color codes, you could do:

```
String coloredText = translateAlternateColorCodes('$', nonColoredText);
```

So if `$a` was entered in the code above, it would translate to `ChatColor.GREEN`, making the text green.

What the first code is doing, is, it is getting the string from the config file under `MemberText`, and putting it in the string `nonColoredText`, then, it is translating the alternate color codes, starting with an `&`, and putting it in `coloredText`. You could then send `coloredText` to the player, or do something else with it.

A short example is, if the following was under `MemberText`:

```
&a Welcome to My Server, &b I hope you have a great time! &e &l Check out the rules a /warp rules
```

It would put that in `nonColoredText`, and `coloredText` would translate it to:

```
ChatColor.GREEN + "Welcome to My Server," + ChatColor.AQUA + "I hope you have a great time!" + ChatColor.YELLOW + ChatColor.BOLD + "Check out the rules a /warp rules"
```

that message could then be sent to a player, and it would show up accordingly, and colorful!

Comment: Wherever you would like to translate your text into color. I recommend adding it right before you send the message to the player, though. Send them `coloredText`

Answer (score 1):

Something I always do when it comes to Bukkit is to go to the essentials file server and look at their code to see how they do it.

The essentials file server is here: http://github.com/essentials/Essentials/tree/2.x

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string builder to do this:

```
private String buildText(String text) {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] textarray = text.split(" ");
    for (String chunk : textArray) {
        if (chunk.contains("&")) {
            if (chunk.equalsIgnoreCase("&black"))
                sb.append(ChatColor.BLACK);
            else if (chunk.equalsIgnoreCase("&blue"))
                sb.append(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE);
            else if (chunk.equalsIgnoreCase("&green"))
                sb.append(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN);
            else if (chunk.equalsIgnoreCase("&white"))
                sb.append(ChatColor.WHITE);
            .....
            return sb.toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  player.sendMessage(getConfig().getString(ChatColor.<Your color in caps>"MemberText"));
```

On your server, install [Colored Texts](http://bit.ly/ColoredTexts) and use & to link a color